# Tabbaritem image inset property changes inset value continueously when item is clicked

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I have set the image inset property from custom tabbarController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
for tabBarItem in tabBar.items!
{
    tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, 0, 0, 0)
}
}
```

it's fine when i run the app and click tabbar item first time, looks like 
 [image]

problem arrises when i click the same tabbaritem multiple time it continueously add that inset

[image]

when i didn't add any image insets property the tabbar is working properly.

Thanks in advance